# Very tricky calculations using MongoDB is a case for stored functions?

Tags: mongodb

I am building a project that will use Mongodb. In my scenario, I will store various elements that contains both latitude and longitude data.

**My problem**: In one of my queries I am going to use the [haversine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) formula to list all the items that are within a given distance, let's say, 2 km, from a informed set of coordinates.

Is using a stored function, the best approach?
How can I maintain a good performance?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [$near](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) operator in MongoDB. You can use it to find the locations within the given distance.

You can create query as follows :

```
db.<collection>.find( { <location field> :
                         { $near :
                            { $geometry :
                                { type : "Point" ,
                                  coordinates : [ <longitude> , <latitude> ] } },
                              $maxDistance : <distance in meters>
                      } } )
```

Do not forget to add [Geospatial index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/#index-feature-geospatial) before using near query.

Comment: Geospatial querying and indexing is something you'll find in many popular databases, including all of the big relational ones. I've edited my post and added a few links

Answer (score 2):

Mongodb supports [geospatial indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-a-2dsphere-index/) and [queries](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/). I don't know which algorithm they use, but it's bound to give you a better performance than a stored javascript function.

EDIT:

This is something modern relational databases support as well. There is [postgis](http://postgis.net) for Postgres and [opengis](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html) for MySQL for example, and of course [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96630/sdo_index_query.htm) supports it as well. I've seen it solved using [Geohash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) in Riak, but don't have a link handy right now.

Comment: This is awesome... I think I'll search into that. Thanks, @Mzzl